# How to add Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache in angular 8

Tags: angular

where to add Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache in angular 8 .

i have one web api which is returning some data .so we need to write this in web api webconfig or angular index.html or angular web config .

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `HttpInterceptor` to modify the headers on each request.

#### cache.interceptor.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const httpRequest = req.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache'
      })
    });

    return next.handle(httpRequest);
  }
}
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CacheInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> https://medium.com/@tltjr/disabling-internet-explorer-caching-in-your-angular-5-application-3e148f4437ad
>
> https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor
>
> https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/